# How to probe if a file was download using Selenium/WebdriverIO

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I want to know how I can verify if a file was downloaded using Selenium Webdriver after I click the download button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question doesn't say whether you want to confirm it locally or remotely(like browserstack) . If it is remotely then my answer will be "**NO**" as you can see that the file is getting downloaded but you can not access the folder. So you wont be able to assert that the file has been downloaded.

If you want to achieve this locally(in Chrome) then the answer is "**YES**", you can do it something like this:

In wdio.conf.js(To know where it is getting downloaded)

```
var path = require('path');

const pathToDownload = path.resolve('chromeDownloads');

// chromeDownloads above is the name of the folder in the root directory
exports.config = {
capabilities: [{
        maxInstances: 1,     
        browserName: 'chrome',
        os: 'Windows',      
        chromeOptions: {
            args: [
                'user-data-dir=./chrome/user-data',
            ],
            prefs: {
                "download.default_directory": pathToDownload,
            }
        }
    }],
```

And your spec file(To check if the file is downloaded or not ?)

```
const fsExtra = require('fs-extra');
const pathToChromeDownloads = './chromeDownloads';

describe('User can download and verify a file', () =>{

    before(() => {
        // Clean up the chromeDownloads folder and create a fresh one
        fsExtra.removeSync(pathToChromeDownloads);
        fsExtra.mkdirsSync(pathToChromeDownloads);
    });

    it('Download the file', () =>{
        // Code to download 
    });

    it('Verify the file is downloaded', () =>{
        // Code to verify 
        // Get the name of file and assert it with the expected name
    });
});
```

more about fs-extra : https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! You save my day. Additional, if you want to set Mozilla download dir: `"browser.download.dir": pathToDownload`. Additional tabs information about Mozilla you can find here: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_:_FAQs_:_About:config_Entries. They can be useful for setting auto dismiss prompt and stuff.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:** Unless your web-app has some kind of visual/GUI trigger once the download finishes (some text, an image/icon-font, push-notification, etc.), then the answer is a resounding **NO**.

Webdriver can't go outside the scope of your browser, but your underlying framework can. Especially if you're using **NodeJS**. :)

Off the top of my head I can think of a few ways I've been able to do this in the past. Choose as applicable:

> **1.** Verify if the file has been downloaded using Node's **[File System](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)** (aka `fs`)

Since you're running WebdriverIO, under a NodeJS environment, then you can make use its powerful lib tool-suite. I would use `fs.exists`, or `fs.existsSync` to **verify if the file is in the expected folder**.

If you want to be diligent, then also use `fs.statSync` in conjunction with `fs.exists` & **poll the file until it has the expected size** (e.g.: `> 2560 bytes`)

There are multiple examples online that can help you put together such a script. Use the `fs` documentation, but **[other](https://techoverflow.net/2012/09/16/how-to-get-filesize-in-node-js/)** resources as well. Lastly, you can add said script inside your `it`/`describe` statement (I remember your were using Mocha).

> **2.** Use `child_process`'s **[exec](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)** command to launch third-party scripts

Though this method requires more work to setup, I find it more relevant on the long run.

**!!! Caution:** Apart from launching the script, you need to write a script in a third-party framework.

- Using an **[AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)** script;
- Using a **[Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/)** script;
- Using a TestComplete (not linking it, I don't like it that much), or [**insert GUI verification script here**] script;

**Note:** All the above frameworks can generate an `.exe` file that you can trigger from your WebdriverIO test-cases in order to check if your file has been downloaded, or not.

**Steps to take:**

- create one of the stand-alone scripts like mentioned above;
- place the script's `.exe` file inside your project in a known folder;
- use `child_process.exec` to launch the script and assert its result after it finishes its execution;

**Example:**

```
exec = require('child_process').exec;
// Make sure you also remove the .exe from scriptName
var yourScript = pathToScript + scriptName;

var child = exec(yourScript); 
child.on('close', function (code, signal) {
    if (code!==0) {
        callback.fail(online.online[module][code]);
    } else {
        callback();
    } 
});
```

**Finally:** I'm sure there are other ways to do it. But, your main take-away from such a vague question should be: **YES**, you can verify if the file has been downloaded if you absolutely must, expecially if this test-case is **CRITICAL** to your regression-run.

Comment: Hey men, I understand clearly, the thing is, I push some download button in my system and then the file begin to download but i don't know which name this file have. If I use the the fs.exists I need to pass the name right? so how do a catch this name after the download begin?

Comment: Hi @iamdanchiv, yeah I know is getting hard, the file change name if I select different row, how can I capture the file name if I want to use selenium WDIO with chrome or firefox? I already know where the file is store. this is a screencast http://take.ms/UjZQL

Comment: ohh @iamdanchiv, sorry I think you missunderstood me hehe, I know i can store the file name in a variable, then compare the name with the file name in the download folder, if exist good, if not bad for me. What i mean was if I dont have a predefined name to store in a variable and search in the download folder, how can I capture the name of the file when it start to download with webdriverIO?

Comment: Let me explain to you more deeply, there is a invoice module that contain a grid with differents invoices(rows) so for example @iamdanchiv this is the file name "Factura_de_venta_VE555154195025.pdf" of the first row of the invoice grid, but the code after the "Factura de venta" could change if you download another invoice(press download invoice in the second row of invoices grid for example), there is no way to get the name before the download, you know the name is after the download starts, so how can i search it in the download folder if I dont have the exact file name?

Comment: Is there a way using  webdriver to detect the lastest download the browser had or extract the lastest download file name? this is a screenshot of the grid http://take.ms/J2T6i

Comment: why the changing part is no need it? this file are downloaded to in this case to some download folder in AWS (all test are remotely), each file of each row has the "Factura_de_venta" part, the only thing that make the difference is the changing part, so how can I detect the last downloaded file using the FS?I mean, if yesterday I downloaded some file and today another, this two file would have the  "Factura_de_venta" part and I need for example the today file, I think I couldn't identified without the changing part name