# How can I verify if a file is downloaded successfully using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, download, nightwatch.js

Is there any way to verify if file is downloaded successfully using JavaScript? Other frameworks used in the project are Selenium, Cucumber, Nightwatch.

I've found few solutions written in C, but actually are not applicable in my project.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44960666/how-to-probe-if-a-file-was-download-using-selenium-webdriverio

Comment: Please check that answer for a potential solution.

Comment: Thanks @C.Peck, It is not a duplicate. The particular answer is using other node.js framework (webdriver.io). Unfortunately, it doesn't work in my project

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, Selenium in Javascript uses Node.js. If that is what you are leveraging, this might be your answer:

https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-check-if-file-exists-node/

However, if you are using Javascript within a browser, such as in a selenium driver executor for other languages, this will not be possible, as browsers do not offer javascript visibility into the host machine for security reasons (although they may offer API's for seeing if a download completed, but I'm not aware of any).

Comment: Thanks! Works perfect